# AngularJS: Directive not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I find myself writing the same "search" UI on every module. So I've decided to write a directive, which I understand injects code as a module so that I can re-use it everywhere.

Note: Without this directive, everything works. I am just trying to understand how to write directives properly. Here is my code:

My directive:

```
var app = angular.module("azucarWeb", []);
app.directive("buscadorPorLapso", function() {
    return {
        template : '<article ng-show="mostrarBuscador" class="buscadorPorLapso">
            <br/>
            <input ng-keypress="traerDatos($event)" ng-model="lapso" type="tel" maxlength="6" class="lapso" placeholder="lapso">
            <button ng-click="traerDatos()">buscar</button>        
            <br/>
        </article>'
    };
});
```

My view:

```
<section class="lo-nuevo">    
        <buscador-por-lapso></buscador-por-lapso>
        <div id="tabla">
        </div>
</section>
```

My controller:

```
angular.module('azucarWeb.CM_prendasPorM2',
        [
            //in here all dependencies of this module
            //any module going to or from here must be injected here
        ])

    //configure the state and url address for this module
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('CM_prendasPorM2', {
                url: '/CM_prendasPorM2',
                templateUrl: 'vistasYControladores/CM_prendasPorM2/CM_prendasPorM2.html',
                controller: 'CM_prendasPorM2Ctrl'
            });
    })
    .controller('CM_prendasPorM2Ctrl', function($scope, $state, cssInjector, $http) {

        $scope.goToWebsite = function(address){
            window.open(address, '_blank');
        };
});//close controller
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can separate some stuff here. I like to separate directives, controllers, factories in their own file. So you could have a directive file lets say myDirective.js then in that file add

`angular.module("buscadorPorLapso", [])
       .directive("buscadorPorLapso", function() {
    return {
        restrict    : 'EA',
        templateUrl : 'path/to/html/file/youwant'
    };
});`

Also all your html make a file for that and plug that file path in the templateUrl above. Than, inject buscadorPorLapso in your main app.js file as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller is taking in `buscadorPorLapso` as a provider. Taking it out should get you past this error. Is there a reason you passed it into the controller?

```
.controller('CM_prendasPorM2Ctrl', function($scope, $state, cssInjector, $http) {

    $scope.goToWebsite = function(address){
        window.open(address, '_blank');
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're missing restrict: 'E', by default it's AC, which is attribute and class, and second add that template into a HTML file, you can't write HTML multiline like that.